# Creating a custom tokenizer in ElasticSearch NEST

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-net

I have a custom class in ES 2.5 of the following:

```
Title
DataSources
Content
```

Running a search is fine, except with the middle field - it's built/indexed using a delimiter of '|'.

> ex: "|4|7|8|9|10|12|14|19|20|21|22|23|29|30"

I need to build a query that matches some in all fields AND matches at least one number in the DataSource field.

So to summarize what I currently have:

```
    QueryBase query = new SimpleQueryStringQuery
    {
        //DefaultOperator = !operatorOR ? Operator.And : Operator.Or,
        Fields = LearnAboutFields.FULLTEXT,
        Analyzer = "standard",
        Query = searchWords.ToLower()
    };
    _boolQuery.Must = new QueryContainer[] {query};
```

That's the search words query.

```
    foreach (var datasource in dataSources)
    {
        // Add DataSources with an OR
        queryContainer |= new WildcardQuery { Field = LearnAboutFields.DATASOURCE, Value = string.Format("*{0}*", datasource) };
    }
    // Add this Boolean Clause to our outer clause with an AND
    _boolQuery.Filter = new QueryContainer[] {queryContainer};
}
```

That's for the datasources query. There can be multiple datasources.

It doesn't work, and returns on results with the filter query added on. I think I need some work on the tokenizer/analyzer, but I don't know enough about ES to figure that out.

EDIT: Per Val's comments below I have attempted to recode the indexer like this:

```
        _elasticClientWrapper.CreateIndex(_DataSource, i => i
            .Mappings(ms => ms
                .Map<LearnAboutContent>(m => m
                    .Properties(p => p
                        .String(s => s.Name(lac => lac.DataSources)
                            .Analyzer("classic_tokenizer")
                            .SearchAnalyzer("standard")))))
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(an => an.Analyzers(a => a.Custom("classic_tokenizer", ca => ca.Tokenizer("classic"))))));
        var indexResponse = _elasticClientWrapper.IndexMany(contentList);
```

It builds successfully, with data. However the query still isn't working right.

New query for DataSources:

```
        foreach (var datasource in dataSources)
        {
            // Add DataSources with an OR
            queryContainer |= new TermQuery {Field = LearnAboutFields.DATASOURCE, Value = datasource};
        }
        // Add this Boolean Clause to our outer clause with an AND
        _boolQuery.Must = new QueryContainer[] {queryContainer};
```

And the JSON:

```
{"learnabout_index":{"aliases":{},"mappings":{"learnaboutcontent":{"properties":{"articleID":{"type":"string"},"content":{"type":"string"},"dataSources":{"type":"string","analyzer":"classic_tokenizer","search_analyzer":"standard"},"description":{"type":"string"},"fileName":{"type":"string"},"keywords":{"type":"string"},"linkURL":{"type":"string"},"title":{"type":"string"}}}},"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1483992041623","analysis":{"analyzer":{"classic_tokenizer":{"type":"custom","tokenizer":"classic"}}},"number_of_shards":"5","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"iZakEjBlRiGfNvaFn-yG-w","version":{"created":"2040099"}}},"warmers":{}}}
```

The Query JSON request:

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "fields": [
              "_all"
            ],
            "query": "\"housing\"",
            "analyzer": "standard"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "DataSources": [
              "1"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to create a custom analyzer with a [classic tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-classic-tokenizer.html) which will break your `DataSources` field into the numbers composing it, i.e. it will tokenize the field on each `|` character.

So when you create your index, you need to add this custom analyzer and then use it in your `DataSources` field:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "number_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "number_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "number_tokenizer": {
          "type": "classic"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": { 
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "DataSources": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "number_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, if you index the string `"|4|7|8|9|10|12|14|19|20|21|22|23|29|30"`, you `DataSources` field will effectively contain the following array of token: `[4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 191, 20, 21, 22, 23, 29, 30]`

Then you can get rid of your `WildcardQuery` and simply use a `TermsQuery` instead:

```
terms = new TermsQuery {Field = LearnAboutFields.DATASOURCE, Terms = dataSources }
// Add this Boolean Clause to our outer clause with an AND
_boolQuery.Filter = new QueryContainer[] { terms };
```

Comment: Can you provide the NEST equivalent to the JSON functions you specified above? And is there anyway to just annotate the custom class?

Comment: You can find a sample NEST equivalent here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193800/creating-a-custom-analyzer-in-elasticsearch-nest-client/25219676#25219676

Comment: Thanks Val, the NEST example appears to be out of date. Is there a more current version (2.5 at least)?

Comment: Nice, can you run this and edit your question with the results: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index_name`

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: You also need to set the search_analyzer on your `DataSources` using `SearchAnalyzer("standard")`

Comment: Did you make sure to delete your index and repopulate it?

Comment: Yes of course. Just updated the JSON in post to reflect changes.

Comment: Ok everything works ok on my side for a few OR'ed `term` queries (even though you should use a `terms` one like in my answer), now can you show the generated JSON query that you get?

Comment: Updated the code to use terms instead - no dice. I updated the post with the request JSON - maybe something wrong with my main keyword part?

Comment: Oh wait, the mapping has a field `dataSources` and in your query you have `DataSources`, that's probably the issue.

Comment: dataSources is a string list of search objects. The field in the POCO object is DataSources. That looks correct to me...

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the `dataSources` variable in your code, but the field you use in your query (i.e. `DataSources`) must be named exactly the same way as the field you have in your mapping (i.e. `dataSources`). Compare the JSON query with your JSON mapping and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hey. Just asked a similar question (this answer didn't help) that maybe you can help with?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546040/custom-tab-tokenizer-in-elasticsearch-nest-2-4

Comment: I'll check but feel free to tell Russ Cam that you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

At an initial glance at your code I think one problem you might have is that any queries placed within a filter clause will not be analysed. So basically the value will not be broken down into tokens and will be compared in its entirety.

It's easy to forget this so any values that require analysis need to be placed in the must or should clauses.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but I know that even if I switch it back over to being a part of the query it wouldn't matter - still doesn't work.